# Graphing based on several columns in R

Tags: r, data-structures, graphing

I have a data structure, and I need to graph the dyads by the variables in one column and the variables in another. For example, say I have a survey and one column is about how students feel about a class  with "strongly agree", "agree", "neutral", "disagree", and "strongly disagree" as options. On another column I have the grade levels of those who took the survey. How would I sort out and graph this data so that I can have show how many people in one grade said "strongly agree", how many in one grade said "agree", etc. for all the grades?

Example data:

```
set.seed(123)
feelops <- c("strongly agree", "agree", "neutral", "disagree", "strongly disagree")
feelops <- ordered(feelops,levels=feelops)
dat <- data.frame(feel=sample(feelops,100,replace=TRUE) , grade=sample(LETTERS[1:5],100,replace=TRUE))

> head(dat)
               feel grade
1             agree     C
2          disagree     B
3           neutral     C
4 strongly disagree     E
5 strongly disagree     C
6    strongly agree     E
```

Comment: I have added some example data to your question. The issue remains however - how do you want to graph this data? One plot? Multiple plots? Barplots? Lines?

Comment: barplot! thanks for helping, by the way.. I have been browsing the internet for hours with no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `barplot` and the example data, something like this might work:

```
barplot(
  with(dat,prop.table(table(feel,grade))),
  beside=TRUE,
  xlab="Grade",
  ylab="% Feeling Within Grade Group",
  col=grey((1:5)/5)
)
legend("topright",as.character(feelops),fill=grey(1:5/5))
```

You can play around with the options a bit, but this will give something like:

[image]

Comment: oh my gosh, thank you so much!!!! one more question though: Is there any way to change the Grade names from A B C to Freshmen, sophomore, etc?

Comment: @sadfrogger - sure - you can change the names when plotting by specificying `names.arg=c("Freshman","Sophomore",etc)` in the `barplot` call or you can rename the values in your input dataset `dat` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use higher level plot packages like `ggplot2` or `lattice`. They are much flexible than the base package. Here I am using `barchart` to create 2 version of barplots. The second one use `reshape2` to put data in longer format generally more suitable for such plots.

```
library(lattice) 
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)

dat1 <- with(dat,prop.table(table(grade,feel)))
p1 <- barchart(dat1, groups=0)
dat.m <- melt(dat1)
p2 <- barchart(value~grade,groups=feel,data= dat.m, auto.key=TRUE)
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]